# One part of the model looks glossy?

Tags: shaders

Why does the head look so shiny compared to the body? I haven't added any texture yet, I think. (I'm still new to blender) I tried changing the matcap but it still looks very glossy. How can I get rid of the glossy look?
[image: model]

Comment: That is, the matcap, maybe try removing the macap? Also, it might be your normals, in edit mode with everything selected, hit Ctrl-N.

Comment: @ GiantCowFilms Please add the answer to the question as I have copied your comment which seems to have answered the issue here but PGMath is getting all worked up because I did so. Please add your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to recalculate normals by selecting the whole object in edit mode and using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

Comment: If you mention a hotkey, it would be useful to either give the hotkey or the menu path to the function. In this case: Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside